# Can I see the video feed of a person who shares the screen with me in Skype (Windows Store)?

Tags: windows-10, skype

I am using Skype on Windows 10, the version which comes from Windows Store. Say, someone shares their screen with me during a video call. Now, I can only see this person's screen and myself in the lower right corner, but I can no longer see my interlocutor. Is there a way I can see them? They can still see themselves in their Skype window, so their camera is on, even though it appears useless at this moment.

Comment: interlocutor, What?

Comment: Upvote just for using the word "interlocutor"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is no longer possible to simultaneously share the screen and view the camera of the person sharing the screen.  According to this post on the Microsoft website, it seems they have removed this feature:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_win10-skype_callms-skype_audioms/share-desktop-and-camera-at-the-same-time/83395d8a-b9cb-4d83-861d-e31446d5d109

I've been looking for additional information on any updates made to get it back, some people have said it is still possible and that the feature might not appear if the connection is bad, but I am  not so sure as I haven't read anything anywhere that states this from Skype support..